# Calculating REM, EM and PX values in normalize.css for font sizing and margins etc

Tags: css, normalize

I've recently become a big fan of [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css)

In the past, I've used [this](http://gregrickaby.com/using-the-golden-ratio-and-rems/) super easy method to calculate my font sizes, line height, margin and padding calculations. However, the sizing structure via [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css) is completing confusing me.

For example. Via the `body` tag, font-size is being calculated in REMs and PX and line-height is being calculated in unitless values:

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Whilst margins and padding is being calculated in EMs:

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

How is everything being calculated? Let's say I want to add a margin of 24px to my `<p>` tag. This is not a method I've come across before and it's important I understand the logic so I can correctly calculate everything. Any links you can provide to further reading is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample

> The em and ex units depend on the font and may be different for each
>   element in the document. The em is simply the font size.

All you need to know is here: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Since `em` is the body's set font, this will give 24px margin

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
div {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
p {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<div></div>
```

And this will give 45px margin

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}
div {
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
p {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<div></div>
```